# "I am going to have a walk"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

My teacher said "I am going to *have* a walk" today in class and to me it seems incorrect. Correct variants that I know are:

- Going for a walk
- Going to take a walk
- Going to walk
- ...

Is this correct? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

You could say "I am going to have a walk" and although it seems a bit clunky to me it is quite understandable.

Going *for* a walk and going *to take* a walk would both work well, the first is maybe more British English the latter more US English but they are the most common ways one would use that phrase.

"Going to walk" is not a statement in itself, it needs a destination - "I'm going to walk to the shops" would be fine but if you had no destination in mind or you didn't want to say what your destination was you would just say "I'm going for a walk."

Comment: "Going to walk" sounds correct, as "walk" is a verb in that context, isn't it?

Comment: @Corey: "I'm going to walk" is a bit awkward, and it definitely feels incomplete: typically *walk* without a destination implies *giving up* or *walking out on* something. "Are you going to accept the contract? No, I'm going to walk."

Comment: It could be used in a context such as: "are you going to drive to the shops?"; "no, I'm going to walk" - though obviously not if you live in LA :-)

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff's example is good but the destination is still being provided by the other person in the dialogue, so although the person speaking is only saying "I'm going to walk" the overall semantic construct is  still "I'm going to walk to the shops."

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this construction. It sounds more British than American, for some reason, but if you can have a fight, or have a bath, or have a go at something, why can't you have a walk?

Comment: In theory yes, but in practise, I agree with glenatron that it somehow sounds a bit odd.

Comment: You can, but you don't. Don't expect to find perfect logic in describing language.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. I agree that it sounds more British than American. Americans tend to prefer "take" in expressions such as "take a shower," while British English will also use "have." See this link: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv343.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Here’s why it sounds weird for me to hear “have a walk”:

[image]

This graph is a search in the [corpus of contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `_v* a walk`  where `_v*` matches verbs and everything is grouped by lemma. I cut the rest of the graph off, but it wasn’t really relevant because everything is less frequent and the words aren’t synonymous with “take a walk”.

As for the expressions that do show up: “be a walk” doesn’t return relevant results (eg “be a walk in the park”), “draw a walk” is sports (baseball?) and the other categories should be pretty obvious in meaning.

---

Here is that same search in the British national corpus:

[image]

As you can see “take a walk” is still the most popular, but “have a walk” is also popular, so that’s why it sounds natural to British people to “have a walk”.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if any of those BrEng citations are quoting Lou Reed's iconic song [**take a] [walk on the wild side**](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=a6csXNS2B8-ckgWryKrACw&q=%22take+a+walk+on+the+wild+side%22&oq=%22take+a+walk+on+the+wild+side%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67l2j0j0i67j0l6.10578.16595..17700...0.0..0.118.411.2j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i13.XR2Z-lDjFO0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Looks like 4 in BNC and 25 in COCA. Neither is enough to upset the results.