# Why is "having a walk" incorrect?

Tags: word-choice

> I was **having a walk** when the dog suddenly bit me.

My colleague felt 'having a walk' is not appropriate, and that the correct expression is 'going for a walk' or 'taking a walk'.

Why is "having a walk" incorrect?

Comment: I have noticed that British people are often more likely to use "have" about certain things where Americans say "take", e.g. walks, baths, breaks.

Comment: Your colleague is right. *have* is not an idiomatic collocation with *walk* -- *take* is. Look up use cases in a good dictionary.

Comment: Kris, _have_ is a perfectly idiomatic collocation with _walk_ for a large and significant  part of the Anglosphere.

Comment: Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/i-am-going-to-have-a-walk

Comment: Thank you for asking. When a question asks for proofreading or rewriting (“how should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, “which is correct?”), that is out of scope for this site and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Comment: I had a long walk today with my dog.  Did you have a good walk along the Towpath?   It doesn't sound as though there is anything wrong with these two sentences to this US English speaker.

Comment: @MetaEd Can you hammer-close as duplicate now?

Comment: @Chappo the older question is not among the greatest, I felt constrained to upvote two answers to legitimize this closure. If the OP were present, I would ask them to expand their question ever so slightly but "how" I would not know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree the older isn’t great, but this question is so similar it makes sense to mark it as a dupe. The solution is to encourage a *good* answer to the older one. I’m working to get to 3000 rep to unlock privileges, so I can’t afford to offer a bounty, but maybe someone with “spare” points could put a bounty on it? ;-)

Comment: @Chappo I have tons of rep but the question doesn't really interest me. I'm sorry. And I don't think anyone will really post that "special" answer that makes you say "wow". Not for that one.

Comment: Yes, no “wow” factor here. Dare I say it’s a somewhat *pedestrian* question ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence is grammatically correct.

'To have a walk' is similar to such phrases as 'to have a shower / lunch, etc.

The phrase 'to take a walk' is a synonym of  'to have a walk'.

'To go for a walk' is not appropriate in your case because it is used rather for an intention to walk than a process of walking.

Comment: I disagree. To me, 'go for a walk' is synonymous with 'take a walk'.

Comment: This "intention" business, which is not really a rule carved in stone, would have some legitimacy if the suggestion had been: "*I was **going to go** for a walk*" Instead, "I ***was going for*** a walk" clearly expresses an action in progressive at the time of speaking. The speaker's intention has little to do with it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA To me, “I was going for a walk when X happened” means that I was just putting on my coat, or on my way out the door – it’s not about intent, but the state of being mid-walk has also not been reached yet. The _go_ bit to me means ‘go out’ or ‘leave’, with _for a walk_ meaning ‘in order to walk for pleasure’, so the present continuous means being in the process of leaving in order to walk for pleasure, i.e., just on the way out the door.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it can be either, it can express a decision taken some time in the past "I'm going to go for a walk" or it can anticipate an action, "We were going to have a walk when it started to rain" (about to)

Comment: @Mari-LouA True in general. With the “when X happened” bit, the premeditated sense becomes at least very unlikely for me. But the main point was that it really cannot refer to being already mid-walk, so while _taking_ and _having_ are both fine here, _going for a walk_ doesn’t work in this context (just not for the reason given in this answer).

Comment: To me this has nothing to do with grammatical or not. "Walk" is a noun, you can have it. The question seems to be a semantic or idiomatic one. Can I "have an electron"? When you think about it "take a walk" should be more strange than "have a walk", as "have" can mean to experience something, like have fun, have difficulty, have dinner. cf. "take fun", "take difficulty" "take dinner".. The claim seems pretty arbitrary unless the insistence is that "take a walk" is idiomatic and "have a walk" isn't, in which case all they're saying is that people usually say X instead of Y, in their opinion

Comment: @Zebrafish I agree with your conclusion and upvoted your comment, but if a *walk* can be *had* because it it a noun, surely it would be no more strange that it can also be *taken*.